# jQuery SlideDown / SlideUp | "FAQ" | Opened

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidedown, slideup

My title doesn't mean anything i guess, but it's complicated to name my problem.

So, i did a section in my html "faq" and when someone click on a question, the answer appaer with a slideDown. If we click on another question, that close the previous one (slideUp) and open this one you just clicked on. And when we click on a question, the color change with a .addClass / removeClass on the element.

The problem that i'm struggling with is the next one : When we load the page, i would like to have an element already opened and just one. When we click on another one, that will close the previous, and so on.

Some code, will speak a little bit better, there's a [`CodePen link`](https://codepen.io/MaxBresil/pen/GQbPbX). I would like to have the second element already opened :)

Thank you !

Comment: What have you tried? Please show us your efforts

Comment: I put that last thing a tried between comments on the jQuery code

Comment: @MaxBresil please include all relevant information in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you call the `slideDown()` function on the element with `open` class on DOM ready. Then, you call `slideUp` method on the element with `open` class and remove the `open` class on click. This should do the trick:

```js
$(function() {
  var $_openedFaq = null;
  
  //calling the slideDown to show the second element in the tabs
  $('a.open').next('p').slideDown();

  function openFaq($__p) {
    $__p.slideDown();
  }


  function closeFaq($__p) {
    $__p.slideUp();
  }

  $('.faq ul li').each(function() {

    var $faq = $(this);
    var $p = $(this).find('p');
    var offset = $(this).offset().top;


    $(this).find('a').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      //on click hide the current active elements and remove the class from current active element
      $('a.open').next('p').slideUp();
      $('a.open').removeClass('open');

      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: offset
      }, 500);

      // Test of code that i'm struggling with

      if ($('.faq ul li').find('a').hasClass("open")) {
        $p = $(this).next('p');
        openFaq($p);
      }

      // End of the test

      if ($_openedFaq != null) {
        closeFaq($_openedFaq.find('p'));

        $_openedFaq.find('a').removeClass("open");
      }


      if (($_openedFaq == null) || (($_openedFaq != null) && !$faq.is($_openedFaq))) {
        openFaq($p);

        $_openedFaq = $faq;

        $p.prev('a').addClass("open");

      } else {
        $_openedFaq = null;
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Conv_Besom';
  src: url('../font/Besom.eot');
  src: local('☺'), url('../font/Besom.woff') format('woff'), url('../font/Besom.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../font/Besom.svg') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

section {
  background-color: #f9b40a;
}

.faq {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  padding-top: 65px;
  padding-bottom: 65px;
}

.faq div.container div.row div.col-sm-6 h1 {
  font-family: 'Source Serif Pro', serif;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.faq div.container div.row div.col-sm-6 ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.faq div.container div.row div.col-sm-6 ul li {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bfbfbf;
  position: relative;
}

.faq div.container div.row div.col-sm-6 ul li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.faq div.container div.row div.col-sm-6 ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #4a4a4a;
  padding-right: auto;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.25s linear;
  -o-transition: color 0.25s linear;
  transition: color 0.25s linear;
}

.faq div.container div.row div.col-sm-6 ul li a:hover {
  color: black;
}

.faq div.container div.row div.col-sm-6 ul li a:hover::after {
  color: black;
}

.faq div.container div.row div.col-sm-6 ul li a::after {
  content: "\f067";
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  color: #f9b40a;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 0;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.25s linear;
  -o-transition: color 0.25s linear;
  transition: color 0.25s linear;
}

.faq div.container div.row div.col-sm-6 ul li a.open {
  color: black;
}

.faq div.container div.row div.col-sm-6 ul li a.open::after {
  content: "\f068";
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  ;
  color: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 0;
}

.faq div.container div.row div.col-sm-6 ul li p {
  font-weight: normal;
  display: none;
}

.faq div.container div.row div.col-sm-6 img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,700" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Serif+Pro" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../includes/css/font-awesome.css">
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="faq">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <h1>FAQs</h1>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Question 1</a>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
            </p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="open" href="#">Question 2</a>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
            </p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Question 3</a>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
            </p>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Question 4</a>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
            </p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <img src="https://media.forgecdn.net/avatars/107/154/636364134932167010.jpeg" alt="Are you ready ?">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you for the explaination, i understood it :D

Answer (score 0):

You could just add `$('.faq ul li a:first').click();` once your page is loaded. That will register the first FAQ as open. I would have it be the last statement of your `$(function(){ ... }` call